# Dataframe Column If Condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I'm trying to analyze nba players dataset for a homework. I have a dataset that includes name, points, assists, year, etc. I'm trying to analyze the players who plays in year 2017 so first I want to print their names, points, assists, etc.

When I try the below code:

```
for i in df1.columns:
    if df1['Year'] == 2017:
         print(df1.loc[:, ["Year","Player","Pos","Team","Games","AST","PTS","PPG"]])
```

I get an error with this code which tells me that adding `.any()` or `.all()` is needed.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-101-c1ff6e025cb7> in <module>()
      1 for i in df1.columns:
----> 2     if df1['Year'] == 2017:
      3          print(df1.loc[:, ["Year","Player","Pos","Team","Games","AST","PTS","PPG"]])

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1574         raise ValueError("The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "
   1575                          "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
-> 1576                          .format(self.__class__.__name__))
   1577 
   1578     __bool__ = __nonzero__

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I added them to the code.

```
for i in df1.columns:
if df1['Year'].all() == 2017:
     print(df1.loc[:, ["Year","Player","Pos","Team","Games","AST","PTS","PPG"]])
```

This code block returns no output (no error or etc.)

Also I think that this can be done with list comprehension but I couldn't find a way. It should be like this:

```
df2 = [df1['Year','Player','Pos','Team','Games','AST','PTS','PPG'] if (df1['Year'].any() == 2017) else "Bye" for i in df1.Year]
    print(df2)
```

But there is a problem here which is, this code always enter the else statement and only prints "Bye".

Comment: why are you iterating by columns ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you just want to print other columns where the year is 2017 you can do this

```
print(df1[df1['Year']==2017].loc[:,["Year","Player","Pos","Team","Games","AST","PTS","PPG"]])
```

without iterating through columns like your doing nor using an if statement, pandas dataframes have good indexation

Comment: I did try that aswell and it gives no error. But it returns an empy output. It just prints me the columns name and didn't return any values.

Comment: are you loading your dataset from a csv file ? and is it loading correctly ?

Comment: After this comment, I found that the dataset was corrupted so I import it again. But the thing is, I need to print specific columns so that I use list comprehension method which always enters the "else" statement.

Comment: you need to print ["Year","Player","Pos","Team","Games","AST","PTS","PPG"] ?

Comment: Yes I need those values

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that gives an error: "KeyError: ('Year', 'Player', 'Pos', 'Team', 'Games', 'AST', 'PTS', 'PPG')". Btw those values names aren't wrong because I copied all of them from the output of "df1.columns"

Comment: no problem i'm really glad helping you, i updated my answer using loc

Comment: It worked :). But I still don't get why my first method doesn't work. The logic behind is same. I only use for loop. Thanks for your help btw :)

Comment: u're welcome. the for loop wasn't really necessary, you were iterating through columns and not using that index. And for the condition, you were comparing a whole dataframe ( column) with an integer, if you wanted the loop method you should go through the rows ( compare each value in year with 2017).